# Android SignalR - get Last Message timestamp

Tags: android, signalr

I'm using the SignalR library: https://github.com/SignalR/java-client

Is there a way to retrieve the timestamp of the last message received on the Android client?

If that's not possible, is there any way of knowing the last time anything happened between the client and the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually 5 days ago, prior to anyone responding, I ended up solving it, with a solution similar to what Kenneth Li is suggesting.

So I feel I'm answering my own question:

I created a timestamp on the client, and keep updating it whenever the client receives anything through the SignalR connection.
That way, I'll always know when the last message was received.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, when the signalr Server receive anything from clients, I create a timestamp in the server and store it using arraylist or sql.  Before sending message to any client, I also create a timestamp in the Server and send the timestamp together with the message to the client, and those messages and timestamps received by the clients will be stored in client side storage using cookie or internalstorage or clientside sqlite or client side file Api depends on what kind of client.